# What is the word for when you beep an item on a cashier?

Tags: word-request

I was always wondering what is the word for when you beep an item on a cashier. I thought it was check out but I'm not sure. I hope you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: _Check out_ is the process of scanning and paying for **all** your items at the cash register. If you are looking for the verb that describes what happens to each item, _scan_ is a good choice, as Max says in the answer.

Comment: A *cashier* is the human who works at the shop, scanning your items for you. When you scan your *own* items, you do it at the *automated check-out*; or the *self-service check-out*.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for *scan*.

> [scan](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scan)
>
> 5. to read (data) for use by a computer or computerized device, especially using an optical scanner.

[image]

Comment: I think you can also say, "[ring up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ring+up)", though ringing up a person is scanning all their items, compared to ringing up an item.